# Ideas for web application with external input and realtime notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, notifications

I am to build a web application which will accept different events from external sources and present them quickly to the user for further actions. I want to use Ruby on Rails for the web application. This project is a internal development project. I would prefer simple and easy to use solutions for rapid development over high reliable and complex systems.

**What it should do**

The user has the web application opened in his browser. Now an phone call comes is. The phone call is registered by a PBX monitoring daemon. In this case via the Asterisk Manager Interface. The daemon sends the available information (remote extension, local extension, call direction, channel status, start time, end time) somehow to the web application. Next the user receives a notified about the phone call event. The user now can work with this. For example by entering a summary or by matching the call to a customer profile.

The duration from the first event on the PBX (e.g. the creation of a new channel) to the popup notification in the browser should be short. Given a fast network I would like to be within two seconds. The single pieces of information about an event are created asynchronously. The local extension may be supplied separate from the remote extension. The user can enter a summary before the call has ended. The end time, new status etc. will show up on the interface as soon as one party has hung up.

The PBX monitor is just one data source. There will be more monitors like email or a request via a web form. The monitoring daemons will not necessarily run on the same host as the database or web server. I do not image the application will serve thousands of logged in users or concurrent requests soon. But from the design 200 users with maybe about the same number of events per minute should not be a scalability issue.

**How should I do?**

I am interested to know how you would design such an application. What technologies would you suggest? How do the daemons communicate their information? When and by whom is the data about an event stored into the main database? How does the user get notified? Should the browser receive a complete dataset on behalf of a daemon or just a short note that new data is available? Which JS library to use and how to create the necessary code on the server side?

On my research I came across a lot of possibilities: Message brokers, queue services, some rails background task solutions, HTTP Push services, XMPP and so on. Some products I am going to look into: ActiveMQ, Starling and Workling, Juggernaut and Bosh.

Maybe I am aiming too hight? If there is a simpler or easier way, like just using the XML or JSON interface of Rails, I would like to read this even more.

I hope the text is not too long :)

Thanks.

Comment: Some weeks late but anyway... I decided to start with low technology. In the browser I use pulling every second. Getting my feet wet showed me that I have to think more about the daemons. there sit a number of questions that have to be addressed. For communication between the daemons and the web application I will go for a RESTful api. Thanks again for your thoughts.

Comment: Small update: I am now moving to the Nginx Http Push Module: http://pushmodule.slact.net/

Comment: are you trying to build http://pusher.com/ ? or could you utilize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip Java and Flash, perhaps it makes sense to use a technology in the Comet family to do the push from the server to the browser?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

For the sake of simplicity, for notifications from daemons to the Web browser, I'd leave Rails in the middle, create a RESTful interface to that Rails application, and have all of the daemons report to it. Then in your daemons you can do something as simple as use curl or libcurl to post the notifications. The Rails app would then be responsible for collecting the incoming notifications from the various sources and reporting them to the browser, either via JavaScript using a Comet solution or via some kind of fatter client implemented using Flash or Java.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this a number of ways but my only comment would be: Push, don't pull. For low latency it's not only quicker it's more efficient, as your server now doesn't have to handle n*clients once a second polling the db/queue. ActiveMQ is OK, but Starling will probably serve you better if you're not looking for insane levels of persistence.

You'll almost certainly end up using Flash on the client side (Juggernaut uses it last time I checked) or Java. This may be an issue for your clients (if they don't have Flash/Java installed) but for most people it's not an issue; still, a fallback mechanism onto a pull notification system might be prudent to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think too I have to use push for messaging from the daemon to the browser. I wonder if I have to put Rails between the daemon and the browser or if I can find a solution where Rails and the browser are listening on the same level. Maybe using something like couchDB as an event storage. I will play a bit with this idea.
Nevertheless I will give Starling a try. It still seems to be popular and there are several exaples with code available.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps http://goldfishserver.com might be of some use to you. It provides a simple API to allow push notifications to your web pages. In short, when your data updates, send it (some payload data) to the Goldfish servers and your client browsers will be notified, with the same data.

Disclaimer: I am a developer working on goldfish.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But a hostet solution is not appropriate for me.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

- There is an event - either external (or perhaps internally within your app).
- Users should be notified.

### One solution

- I am myself facing this problem. I haven't solved it yet, but this is how I intend to do it. It may help you too:

#### (A) The app must learn about the event (via an exposed end point)

- Expose an end point by which you app can be notified about external events.
- When the end point is hit (and after authentication then users need to be notified).

#### (B) Notification

- You can notify the user directly by changing the DOM on the current web page they are on.
- You can notify users by using the Push API (but you need to make sure your browsers can target that).
- All of these notification features should be able to be handled via Action Cable: (i)  either by updating the DOM to notify you when a phone call comes in, or (ii) via a push notification that pops up in your browser.

**Summary:** use Action Cable.

(Also: why use an external service like Pusher, when you have ActionCable at your disposal? Some people say scalability, and infrastructure management. But I do not know enough to comment on these issues. )